# Will TCP ever break up data less than 1kb?

Tags: c#, tcpclient

I'm creating a TCP server. I heard that you can't always count on reading all data with one Read even if it was all sent with one Write. The protocol might break it up. My question is is that just for huge packets or will it even break up 1kb? 500bytes? Is any size safe?

Comment: This is not really a programming question, but rather help with understanding the TCP/IP protocol. For that, I'd recommend using http://www.ietf.org/rfc.html

Comment: I disagree, Morten. Using TCP properly is very much a programming question.

Answer (score 2):

You can never count on reading all data in one read. You can break up packages arbitrarily by setting a small MTU.

Comment: Mensi is right. You can *never* count on reading all the bytes in one read.  Depending on your socket library, you likewise cannot count on *sending* all bytes in one write.

Comment: To be totally pedantic, I guess you can count on reading one byte in one read. (Unless that times out).

Answer (score 1):

When using a TCP socket, you don't control the 'packets' which are sent.  You simply write/read bytes out to/from the socket, and the protocol controls how and when its transmitted.

There is actual a maximum on the amount of data the other side is willing to receive at any one time.  This is known as the "[Maximum segment size](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_segment_size)."  You can't know how big this is, as it is determined by the person you're talking to.  They might only allow you to send data in a maximum of 1k segments, or only 500 byte segments.  There's no way to know, unless you could possibly control both ends.

Also, not only can the bytes you write out be split up into smaller segments, but multiple small writes can actually be combined together into one larger segment.  See [Nagle's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm).